# How to use foreach with AngularJS on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I use a foreach statment in angular js? My current data is printing out as a json format. I want to make it printed out on new lines.

**Html**

```
<p>{{controller.greeting.custinfo}}</p>

 //attempt
<p ng-repeat= >{{controller.greeting.custinfo}}</p>
```

**Output on UI**

```
{"id":null,"biling_address":"null","billing_state":"FL","ip_Addresses":["123:111:2101","","NULL"],name":"jimmmy"}
```

**java output**

```
System.out.println(custinfo);
demo.model.cert@ba1983a
```

How can I use a foreach statement to display the data in new lines? Rather than a json format.

I know how to do this with thymeleaf,example below

```
<table th:each="custinfo : ${custinfo}">

  <tr>
        <td ng-show="id" class="padded">id:</td>
        <td ng-show="id" th:text="${custinfo.id}" class="padded"></td>
  </tr>
  //continue down
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just loop thru it:

```
 <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in controller.greeting.custinfo">{{key}}: {{value}}</p>
```

Comment: In my case what would be key/value?

Comment: On first row: `key = "id"` & `value = "null"`.

Comment: Ok, key would work, but not value. Value changes everytime. So I can't just set the value

Comment: If your object changes, the key/value (output) will change too. Check E2E binding of AngularJS.

Comment: Got it, you gave me the answer. Will accept when times up.

Comment: @Mike.Chun glad to help ya.

Answer (score 3):

To display a list using AngularJS, you need an array that you will iterate.

Let's say you have list of customers

```
$scope.customers = [{id:1, name:'customer1'}, .....];
```

You will do so this

```
 <ul>
<li ng-repeat="custInfo in customers">{{custInfo.name}}       </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS can iterate over object with `ng-repeat`.

```
$scope.data = {"id":null,"biling_address":"null","billing_state":"FL","ip_Addresses":["123:111:2101","","NULL"],"name":"jimmmy"};
```

---

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td class="padded">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example for your data:
https://jsfiddle.net/fn8rqjz2/1/

If you want to show or hide elements based on `id`:

```
<tr ng-show="data.id" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<p ng-repeat="(key, value) in yourObj">{{yourObj[key]}}</p>
```

If I understood what are you trying to do.